# How do I install qps from repositories on ubuntu 13?

Tags: installation, apt, repository, aptitude

I'm trying to install [qps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/qps.1.html) on ubuntu with

```
aptitude install qps
```

Where I get

```
Couldn't find package "qps". ...
```

I probably could download the sources and recompile, but I think I might be missing some repositories or something (and that's a better way because I'll get the updates automatically afterwards).

Can anybody tell me how I can install qpt from repositories, and how I find repositories where the package is located in the future?

Comment: I recommend you to check precise man pages instead http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/qps.1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qps is a visual process status monitor that displays the status of the processes currently  in existence, much like top or ps. The qps package isn't in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 13.04. In order to find the repository that contains qps, visit the [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qps&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) website and search for qps for **Any** Distribution. Alternatively you can open the terminal and run:

```
apt-cache show qps
```

...and then check if there are any results for qps for your version of Ubuntu. qps is found in the **universe** repository for Ubuntu 12.04. ⠀